# Display custom text after date

Tags: datepicker

I'm trying to create a display on a wordpress page that would show inputted text after a set time. I have created a date picker in the wordpress post editor as well as a text box to input the displayed text. I'm selling tickets for events so I would like it to say "Onsale 'date'", then after that date, display the actual ticket price that I've inputed. Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks!

Here's what I have so far

```
    <?php echo get_field('onsale'); 
        if ( time() > strtotime ('onsale')) 
        { get_field('price'); } ?>
```

"onsale" calls the custom date from the datepicker. "price" calls the inputed text field I would like to display after the date. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Posting some codes would be helpful!

Comment: @tousif Just added some code I'm working with.